# I made no change before switching but Eclipse asks me to commit

Tags: git, eclipse, git-branch, git-commit

I have several branches for one project.

Recently, I have a problem every time I switch from one branch to another:

I made NO change, but Eclipse prompts "Checkout conflicts: You have uncommitted changes..." and expects me to commit. In this case, the ONLY unstaged file is .gitignore, NO CODE involved. (See **picture 1**)

To proceed, I have to commit and a comment is required. The comment I usually write is "No change." (See **picture 2**)

In fact, this kind of commit is meaningless because the version of the code has never been changed. The "No change" comment is also recorded in the version history and it's annoying. Since I encounter this problem from time to time, the "No change" comments just cluster my version history. (See **picture 3**)

**I want to get rid of this problem that Eclipse recognizes no change as change and forces me to make meaningless commit.**

**I didn't have this problem before, and things should go like what is shown this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xz0P8Qx0Uz0&list=PLneu2P-az8RtH1HEFgu_Qm3zPFz1yN6bR&index=5** **When the guy switches from one branch to another for an identical project, he just makes it smoothly with no surprising pop-ups.**

**Picture 1**
[image: Picture 1]

**Picture 2**
[image]

**Picture 3**
[image]

Comment: It seems that you right-clicked on a file or folder and chose _Team > Ignore_, which actually created or modified the `.gitignore` file, which in turn represents a change in Git that needs to be committed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm pretty sure I never clicked on Team > Ignore. In fact, that's why this .gitigonre acts so weird. It just happens without any manual configuration.

Comment: Maybe the root case is that the `DBScraper` project does not have a `.gitignore` file containing the line `/bin/` and that the source folder contains a `.gitignore` file that will be automatically copied from the source folder into the output folder `DBScraper/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

Comment: In all branches the `DBScraper` project should have a `.gitignore` file containing the line `/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well, the option to stash or discard the changes in that window weren't even working for some reason. Fixed it by going to Team > Stashes > Stash Changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).